# No method error when passing a block to a method

Tags: ruby

When trying to pass a block to the sum method:

```
def sum(list, &block)
  list.find_all{yield}.reduce(0, :+)
end
sum([12, 14, 0, 7, 56, 0]) {|i| i % 2 == 0}
```

I get this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `%' for nil:NilClass

My method couldn't recognize the `i` as an element in my list. I don't know how fix it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list.find_all { |i| yield i }.reduce(0, :+)
```

or equivalently

```
list.find_all(&block).reduce(0, :+)
```

What you originally wrote searched through the list so that for each element you `yield` - this would invoke the block with no parameters, `i` gets assigned `nil`, and `nil % 2` is bad.

Comment: thank you very much. could you show me where can I find that syntax in the ruby API docs? I couldn't find it in the ruby documentation.

Comment: If you're talking about `&block` I used, [proc to block conversion](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Proc+to+Block+Conversion). `block` is a `Proc` object, created by the [block argument](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument) `&block` in your own code.